# Restricting access to Azure Storage block blob metadata only

Tags: azure, permissions, metadata, storage, blob

Suppose I have a block blob in a private container on Azure Blob Storage. I know of several ways to grant or prevent read access to the blob as a whole. But is it possible to grant access to the blob *contents*, while restricting access to the blob *metadata*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Access to blob's contents is done through [`Get Blob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179440.aspx) operation and based on the documentation this operation returns contents, metadata and properties.

Following is the text from the REST API documentation:

> The Get Blob operation reads or downloads a blob from the system,
>   including its metadata and properties. You can also call Get Blob to
>   read a snapshot.

I guess one option for you would be to read the blob in your application and then stream only blob contents to the client.

Comment: Also consider creating a snapshot of the blob without metadata and then providing access to the snapshot.

Comment: @kwill, that's a really interesting idea!